# i tried to used banner-background however it is not working properly? I have placed this code in my head section

Tags: css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I tried to used banner-background and I have placed this code in  my head section however it is not working properly?

```css
<style>
.banner-background 
{
    clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 91%, 63% 100%, 22% 91%, 0 99%, 0 0);
}
</style>
<!-- banner -->
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0 primary-background">
        <div class="jumbotron primary-background text-light">
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
                <h2>Welcome To TechBlog</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Technical blog i.e World of technology & programming.
                    Programming language is a formal language comprising a set of
                    instructions that produce various kinds of output. Programming
                    languages are used in computer programming to implement algorithms.
                </p>
                <p>Most programming languages consist of instructions for
                    computers. There are programmable machines that use a set of
                    specific instructions, rather than general programming languages.</p>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-light">
                    <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> Start ! its Free
                </button>
                <a  href="login.jsp" class="btn btn-outline-light">
                    <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo6rh.png
```

Comment: Thank you Dale for editing this question. I am new here.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML where you use this CSS, preferably make a working snippet which shows the problem and also clarify what not working means, thanks.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the code. Please help me to correct it.

Comment: Post the code in your question as text so we can copy/paste/run it. The screenshot is not very useful. And make sure the HTML which is actually using `.banner-background` is there - right now it is not in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi, your code picture does not show the relevant HTML please post a Stackoverflow snippet which demonstrates the problem, we need to be able to actually use your code to see what is wrong. Please also explain clearly what it is that is not working.

Comment: Please advise me why clip path is not working,  remaing code is correct.